Ranking highest paid employees in a given Dept over last 5 years
I am trying to rank the top 3 highest paid employees from a given department each year for the last 5 years.
The table contains the following columns:
Employee_ID
Dept_ID
Salary
Year
I'm trying dense_rank but finding it quite confusing

To rank the top 3 highest-paid employees from each department for each of the last 5 years using DENSE_RANK, you can use the following SQL query. This query will partition the data by Dept_ID and Year, and then order the rows within each partition by Salary in descending order. It will assign a dense rank to each row and filter out only the top 3 ranks.
Here’s how you can do it:
SELECT Employee_ID, Dept_ID, Salary, Year, DenseRank
FROM (
        SELECT
            Employee_ID,
            Dept_ID,
            Salary,
            Year,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Dept_ID, Year ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS DenseRank
        FROM Employees
        WHERE 
        Year >= YEAR(GETDATE()) - 5 -- This filters the last 5 years
    ) AS ranked
WHERE 
    DenseRank <= 3
ORDER BY 
    Dept_ID, Year, DenseRank;

